# mysql query in clause at playframework

Tags: java, mysql, sql, scala, playframework

in below two sql query `sql1` not selecting any row, and `sql2` selecting only 1 for `111@k2.com`

```
 var ids="'111@k2.com','222@k2.com','333@k2.com','444@k2.com','555@k2.com','666@k2.com'"

    val sql1 = SQL("SELECT id,point,privacy FROM `pointTable` WHERE state=1 and  id in ({users})").on("users" -> ids)
    sql1().map { row =>
      val point = if (row[Boolean]("privacy")) { row[Double]("point").toString } else { "0" }
      println(write(Map("id" -> row[String]("id"), "point" -> point)))
    }

    val sql2 = SQL("SELECT id,point,privacy FROM `pointTable` WHERE state=1 and  id in (" + ids + ")")
    sql2().map { row =>
      val point = if (row[Boolean]("privacy")) { row[Double]("point").toString } else { "0" }
      println(write(Map("id" -> row[String]("id"), "point" -> point)))
    }
```

in phpmyadmin when i run this query manualy it returns 6 rows then why not working perfectly here.
i am using play framework 2.2 with scala 2.1

Comment: you have not declared ids correctly. there is a problem in placement of your quotes, please check again.

Comment: @aradhna SORRY its by mistake, only here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not going to work. Passing `users` though `on` is going to escape the entire string, so  it's going to appear as *one* value instead of a list. Anorm in Play 2.3 actually allows you to pass lists as parameters, but here you'll have to work around that.

```
val ids: List[String] =  List("111@k2.com", "222@k2.com", "333@k2.com")
val indexedIds: List[(String, Int)] = ids.zipWithIndex

// Create a bunch of parameter tokens for the IN clause.. {id_0}, {id_1}, ..
val tokens: String = indexedIds.map{ case (id, index) => s"{id_${index}}" }.mkString(", ")

// Create the parameter bindings for the tokens
val parameters = indexedIds.map{ case (id, index) => (s"id_${index}" -> toParameterValue(id)) }

val sql1 = SQL(s"SELECT id,point,privacy FROM `pointTable` WHERE state=1 and  id in (${tokens})")
    .on(parameters: _ *)
```